# Отправить/получить данные с cgi-формы в C++Builder6

Tags: c++builder, cgi, web-apps, c++

Есть cgi страница, на ней несколько полей ввода. При вводе информации и нажатии кнопки она загружает страницу с некой информации.

Как с помощью C++Builder заполнить эту форму, нажать кнопку и, подождав ответа, вывести полученую информацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть.
Есть сервер. Который отдает эту страницу, и должен получить от вас данные и передать их на обработку cgi-объекту (скрипту, бинарнику) и потом вернуть вам ответ.

1. (Не обязательный) Кидаем GET-запрос на сервер, забираем страницу. Сравниваем её с той, которую "умеем отправлять". Если не сходится сообщаем, что всё плохо.
2. Заполняем "строку типа" параметр=значение&параметр... которую кидаем на сервер методом POST или GET HTTP-запроса.
3. В том, что получим в ответ пробуем искать нужные сигнатуры (успех-ошибка) или сразу показываем человеку.
   Важно заметить, что вам, как клиенту веба абсолютно безразлично, что за ПО используется на сервере.

Доп. материалы. Протокол НТТР. НТТР идет поверх обычного ТСР-соединения. Хотя в борланде был компонент (что-то типа webClient) который избавит вас от прямой мороки с протоколом.

[Примеры диалогов HTTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B_.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.B2_HTTP).

[Тут](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/HTTP-POST.php#part_3) достаточно подробно расписан метод POST.

По сути проблемы возникнут в двух случаях.
Небольшая - если вам нужно отправлять файлы - сложности с работами с компонентами, и морока с реализацией multipart/form-data кодирование - (на самом деле в загjловке прописывается сигнатура-разделитель, которая и делит блок данных на переменные).

Ну и вторая проблема, что именно вы пишите. Будьте готовы к тому, что на особо интересных проектах администрация считает своим долгом раз в пару недель поменять структуру формы регистрации и авторизации.